# How to get list of newly added files on a branch

Tags: clearcase

How to get list of all newly added files on a branch in clearcase which are already checkedin

Answer (score 1):

You could use a find query in order to list:

- versions only on a certain branch
- created since a certain date

See [IBM find examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425) for more.